# Tensorflow 2.0: flat_map() to flatten Dataset of Dataset returns cardinality -2

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to run the following code (as given in Tensorflow documentation) to create windows of my data and then flatten the dataset of datasets.

```
window_size = 5

windows = range_ds.window(window_size, shift=1)
for sub_ds in windows.take(5):
    print(sub_ds)

flat_windows = windows.flat_map(lambda x: x)
```

The problem is that `flat_windows.cardinality().numpy()` returns cardinality to be -2 which is creating problem for me during training. I tried looking for ways to set_cardinality of a dataset but couldn't find anything. I also tried other ways of flattening a dataset of datasets, but again no success.

**Edit-1:** The problem with the training is that the shape is unknown (at Linear and Dense layers) when I am training a subclass model (given below). The model trains well when I train the model eagerly (through `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)`) but that is slow. Therefore I want the input data to be known for the model training.

## Neural Network

```
class NeuralNetworkModel(tf.keras.Model): 
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetworkModel, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder()        
    
    def train_step(self, inputs):       
        X        = inputs[0]
        Y        = inputs[1] 
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            enc_X    = self.encoder(X)
            enc_Y    = self.encoder(Y)    

            # loss:        
            loss   = tf.norm(enc_Y - enc_X, axis = [0, 1], ord = 'fro')
                
        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.encoder.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value.
        # Note that it will include the loss (tracked in self.metrics).
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result()}
        
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        # We list our `Metric` objects here so that `reset_states()` can be
        # called automatically at the start of each epoch
        # or at the start of `evaluate()`.
        # If you don't implement this property, you have to call
        # `reset_states()` yourself at the time of your choosing.
        return [loss_tracker]
    
    def test_step(self, inputs):       
        X = inputs[0]
        Y = inputs[1] 

        Psi_X    = self.encoder(X)
        Psi_Y    = self.encoder(Y)    

        # loss:        
        loss   = tf.norm(Psi_Y - Psi_X, axis = [0, 1], ord = 'fro')

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        
        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value.
        # Note that it will include the loss (tracked in self.metrics).
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result()}
        
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__(dtype = 'float64', name = 'Encoder')
        self.input_layer   = DenseLayer(128)
        self.hidden_layer1 = DenseLayer(128)
        self.hidden_layer2 = DenseLayer(64)        
        self.hidden_layer3 = DenseLayer(64)
        self.output_layer  = LinearLayer(64)
        
    def call(self, input_data, training):
        fx = self.input_layer(input_data)        
        fx = self.hidden_layer1(fx)
        fx = self.hidden_layer2(fx)
        fx = self.hidden_layer3(fx)
        return self.output_layer(fx)    

class LinearLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(LinearLayer, self).__init__(dtype = 'float64')
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape = (input_dim, self.units), 
                             initializer = "random_normal", 
                             trainable = True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape = (self.units,),    
                             initializer = tf.zeros_initializer(),
                             trainable = True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

class DenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(DenseLayer, self).__init__(dtype = 'float64')
        self.units = units
    
    def build(self, input_shape):
        input_dim = input_shape[-1]
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape = (input_dim, self.units), 
                             initializer = "random_normal", 
                             trainable = True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape = (self.units,),    
                             initializer = tf.zeros_initializer(),
                             trainable = True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
        return tf.nn.elu(x)
```

Comment: This is the desired behavior of the op. Compare [map](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/609bad4d8bd6a00ea3bb95a396c5c5fd434b4c95/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/map_dataset_op.cc#L47) vs. [flat_map](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/609bad4d8bd6a00ea3bb95a396c5c5fd434b4c95/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/flat_map_dataset_op.cc#L46) (i.e. there is no option to preserve cardinality). Maybe reformat your question and elaborate on why this is causing issues during training.

Comment: Thanks @gobrewers14 for a quick response. I have updated issues related to model training.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about this as well. Turns out that -2 is `tf.data.UNKNOWN_CARDINALITY` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data#UNKNOWN_CARDINALITY), which represents that TF doesn't know how many elements the `flat_map` returns per item.

I just asked [Windowing a TensorFlow dataset without losing cardinality information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281714/windowing-a-tensorflow-dataset-without-losing-cardinality-information) to see if anyone knows a way to window datasets without losing cardinality.